# Update 2 million rows for 1 column

Tags: c#, t-sql, sap-ase

I have a table with approximately 2 million records. I have to loop through each record and update the effective date. I need to set the day to the first of the month for each date.

If the current date is the first of the month, then ignore.

i.e.

```
    07/01/2018    
    07/21/2018 => 07/01/2018
    08/11/2018 => 08/01/2018
```

Currently, I'm writing this as a C# program and it taking way too long.
Is there a better solution?

Comment: Don't do it row by row, issue a single `UPDATE` command to update all at once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `DATEADD()` and `DATEDIFF()` combination to get the first of the month date

```
UPDATE t
SET    datecol = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '1900-01-01', datecol), '1900-01-01')
FROM   yourtable t;
```

Comment: this doesn't work in sybase ase. I'm getting function DATEDIFF invoked with wrong number of type of argument(s)

Comment: @User11040: you should **add a relevant RDBMS tag** to your question!! `tsql` *usually* (in at least 95% or more of cases) implies Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: ... and remove the **sql-server** tag.

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as:

```
Update myTable 
    set myDate = DateAdd(day, 1-Day(myDate), myDate)
where day(myDate) > 1;
```